# Close another app from an activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-package-managers

How do I close another app from an activity?

I know that I can close another activity using startactivityforintent but how do I do the same process for closing an app which the activity started?

I opened another app as shown below:

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
                Intent intent = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage("package name");
                startActivity(intent);
```

and after a while I tried killing the app as follows :

```
                ActivityManager  manager = (ActivityManager)getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
                List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> listOfProcesses =     manager.getRunningAppProcesses();
                for (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo process : listOfProcesses)
                {
                    if (process.processName.contains("package name"))
                    {

                        manager.killBackgroundProcesses(process.processName);
                        break;
                    }
                }
```

The process got killed but the app did not close. How do i go about closing the app from my activity?

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know  killBackgroundProcesses (String packageName) is for API 8 and above.

Have the system immediately kill all background processes associated with the given package. This is the same as the kernel killing those processes to reclaim memory; the system will take care of restarting these processes in the future as needed.

Only Android OS can kill the application and Most of the application in the market don't kill the app they just restart the process.

and if u have forgot to add this permission, then add in ur manifest

```
<android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS">
<android:name="android.permission.KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES">
```

Hope this helps u...